# How to identify unique rows and unique observations in a data.frame, based on time variable

Tags: r, dataframe, unique

I have the following data:

```
d <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7), 
             year=c(1999,1999,1999,2000,2000,2000,2000), 
             var1=c(1,1,2,1,4,1,8),
             var2=c(1,1,2,1,5,2,0),
             var3=c(0,0,0,0,7,0,0))

> d
  id year var1 var2 var3
1  1 1999    1    1    0
2  2 1999    1    1    0
3  3 1999    2    2    0
4  4 2000    1    1    0
5  5 2000    4    5    7
6  6 2000    1    2    0
7  7 2000    8    0    0
```

I want to evaluate each row of the data.frame and return a score in a new variable named 'comb'.

If a row holds a combination among var1-var3 that is:

- never observed in previous years (but elements are) --> assign comb=1
- contains an element that is never seen in previous years --> assign comb=2
- never observed in previous years and holds a new element --> assign comb=3
- observed in previous years --> assign comb=0

Some side notes:

- The order of occurrence does not matter (1,1,2 == 1,2,1)
- Duplicate combinations in the same year may be flagged the same

In the example data, this should look like this:

```
d2 <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7), 
            year=c(1999,1999,1999,2000,2000,2000,2000), 
            var1=c(1,1,2,1,4,1,8),
            var2=c(1,1,2,1,5,2,0),
            var3=c(0,0,0,0,7,0,0),
            comb=c(3,3,3,0,3,1,2))
> d2
  id year var1 var2 var3 comb
1  1 1999    1    1    0    3
2  2 1999    1    1    0    3
3  3 1999    2    2    0    3
4  4 2000    1    1    0    0
5  5 2000    4    5    7    3
6  6 2000    1    2    0    1
7  7 2000    8    0    0    2
```

Note that the second row is assigned comb=3 because it is the first year we observe that combinations. If this observation was in year=200 (like row 4), it is assigned a zero.

Is this possible? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: In your output, the second row seems to be already present in that year, why is not 0?

Comment: Can you write detailed notes in the output to describe what you want it to look like?

Comment: @adiana : I want to flag each duplicate observation in a given year the same.

Comment: @InfiniteFlashChess : I provided a more detailed description. Is that what you were aiming at with your comment? Thanks for replying!

Comment: I see the issue, hmmm, like adiana mentions why isn't it 0?

Comment: @InfiniteFlashChess : It is theoretically motivated. Ideally I would like to assign duplicates within the same year the same number. This makes the coding much more difficult, I guess.

Comment: Please can you explain better the difference between when it should return 1,2 and 3? It is not very clear

Comment: @adiana : I gave it a shot. Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably better ways for doing this, but here is a possible strategy. First, you can create a string that is combination of `var1...var3`, like this:

```
> d2$var123 <- paste(d2$var1, d2$var2, d2$var3, sep="-")
> d2
  id year var1 var2 var3 var123
1  1 1999    1    1    0  1-1-0
2  2 1999    1    1    0  1-1-0
3  3 1999    2    2    0  2-2-0
4  4 2000    1    1    0  1-1-0
5  5 2000    4    5    7  4-5-7
6  6 2000    1    2    0  1-2-0
7  7 2000    8    0    0  8-0-0
```

At this point, you can simply (1) loop for all the elements; (2) check whether either of the `var` values occurs in `var123` or in a list of all previous `var1...var3` columns, and then assign your `comb` value accordingly. Here is a bit of pseudocode:

```
d2$comb <- 0  # Initialize column
for (i in unique(d2$id)) {
    previous <- subset(d2, d2$id < i) # All the years before
    current <- subset(d2, d2$id == i) # The current row
    previous_vals <- unique(c(previous$var1, previous$var2, previous$var3)) 
    previous_combos <- unique(previous$var123)

    if (i$var1 %in% previous_vals | i$var1 %in% previous_vals... ) {
        d2$comb([d2$id==1] <- 1
    }
    if (i$var123) %in% previous_combos {
        d2$comb[d2$id==i] <- 0
    }
    .... # Rest of conditions here 
}
```

Comment: `previous` is not just `subset(d2, d2$id < i)` as in this way you are excluding data for the same year which are in the next rows

Comment: I see. Maybe `previous` could be defined as `subset(d2, d2$year <= current$year & d2$id != current$id)`. This way, we can get all the years up to `current`, but still exclude `current`.